# Cannot scrape all html source code with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, html-parsing

I would like to scrape the source code from a website and then parse the code. Unfortunately when I define a variable equal to the innerHTML of the site, it is not pulling all the source code of the website. It is only pulling a subset of the source code and the subset contains none of the data I require (race results). There there a different command I could use? (document.all.innerhtml?)

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Test()
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

URL = 'URL goes here
objIE.navigate (URL)

Do
DoEvents

Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4

htmlData = objIE.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML

MsgBox htmlData
If InStr(htmlData, "<tr class=&Chr(34)&again_bg_table&chr(34)&>") > 0 Then
 'parse code
Else
    MsgBox "The VBA procedure is not designed to parse this webpage. Please modify the code"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the responseText variable instead of the innerHTML variable. 
See this link, however, if you intend to keep using the IE object: http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml

Alternatively use "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" e.g.

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "YOUR URL"
objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
html = objHTTP.responseText
```

**EDIT1:** For future use of scraping / extracting HTML I recommend my Scrape HTML Add-In: http://analystcave.com/excel-scrape-html-add/
The advantage is that there is no need of writing any additional VBA - just specify the right regular expression to capture the needed content.